# What is the german equivalent of "espousal of position"?

Tags: meaning, translation, english-to-german

In the paper "Organizing knowledge syntheses: A taxonomy of literature reviews. Knowledge in Society, 1, (104-126)" of Cooper H.M. he describes a taxonomy of literature reviews. Inside of this taxonomy he assumes that the reviewer of the literature has a position regarding the literature review itself. He argues that the reviewer could either be neutral or 'espousal of position'. While I have an assumption that it means something like *voreingenommen* I'm not able to find a source that proves this translation. Can anyone help me out?

---

Due to clarification reasons I added the taxonomy model, the highlighted fields are the fields which are applying for the work of a different author.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit what is meant by "the reviewer of the literature has a position regarding the [...] review itself"? Am I right to read it in kind of a self-related way, e.g. "the reviewer states that his review is crap / excellent / interesing / boring / meticulously written / carelessly written"? But where would you find such reviews that the reviewer himself judges upon?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear: As far as I understand you can have a different position towards the literature review you are performing. For instance you can either be neutral while reviewing scientific literature or you already have an opinion regarding the literature / topic you are reviewing, this position is then reflected in your literature review.

Comment: "The reviewer could be ... espousal of position" is not correct English. Could you quote the exact wording of the quotation?

Comment: Added the image where it is referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the translation should be more neutral - *voreingenommen* translates into *prejudiced*, which I think doesn't quite hit what the English original says - It rather should be translated, more literally, as maybe

> der Rezensent ist entweder neutral oder [hat|vertritt] bereits eine [Position|Meinung|Ansicht] zum Thema

*voreingenommen* would in most cases lead to the assumption that the reviewer might **oppose** the topic. The English original leaves it open whether the pre-assumptions of the reviewer would be opposing or supporting the subject of review -  he's just assumed to take a position.

Comment: Man kann für oder gegen eine Sache voreingenommen sein.

Comment: @userunknown Das stimmt - Aber "voreingenommen" wird in 90% der Fälle "dagegen" bedeuten.

Comment: Duden: *Vorurteil: ohne Prüfung der objektiven Tatsachen voreilig gefasste oder übernommene, **meist von feindseligen Gefühlen gegen jemanden oder etwas geprägte** Meinung*

Comment: Was ist die Quelle für die 90%? Deine Phantasie? Ist der Wert gleich, egal ob man die Presse betrachtet oder die Literatur? Schriftsprache oder mündliche Rede? Gibt es Berufe, in denen der Begriff vielleicht sehr häufig benutzt wird, so dass deren Verwendung schon 90% der Fälle ausmacht?

Comment: @userunknown Was genau verstehst du an dem fettgedruckten Bestandteil des Kommentars über Deinem nicht?

Comment: Hätte ich erst auf die Fettschreibung reagiert, hättest Du gefragt, was ich an 90% nicht verstehe, wa? Du zitierst den Duden, der manchmal eine gute Quelle ist, zu Vorurteil, nicht zu Voreingenommenheit. Sind aber die meisten Vorurteile von feindseligen Gefühlen geprägt oder wird nur meistens von negativen Vorurteilen geredet/geschrieben? Meinst Du der Duden hat die objektiven Tatsachen diesbezüglich geprüft oder war er vielleicht voreingenommen?

Answer (score 3):

One can either be neutral or

> parteiisch *(biased)*

So this would fit in your table cell, line (4).